# How to apply a git revert?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm working on a git deploy server. I had to reset my local head back a few commits and now im trying to get the server back in sync. I get this error...

```
! [rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward) error: failed to push some refs to server 
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

When I pull it just puts my local repo back before the revert...

Thanks!

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: Sorry, I had just tagged it with everything I'm using so everyone would have all the info.

Comment: the question title is misleading. resetting != reverting. also, you are not applying anything (in the sense of `git apply`), but rather trying to do a non-ff push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(It looks as if you've not only reset back a few revisions, but also create a new commit locally, since otherwise the error would just be "already up to date" or something similar.  You can check this with `git fetch origin` and then `gitk --all`.)

If you're sure that you want to just discard the extra commits on the deploy server's `master`, you can do a force push with:

```
 git push --force origin master
```

Force pushing usually means that you're rewriting history in a way that may be problematic for any collaborators on the project, but I assume that since this is just a server that you push to in order to deploy, it's not one that people are cloning from.  However, if my assumption is wrong, you should rethink this.